# RABL render JSON object if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

Is it possible to/is this the correct syntax for RABL to render an object into JSON if a param equals a certain value?

```
if (event.charge == true) {
  collection @events
  attributes :title, :date, :time, :venue, :description
}
```

I have a page full of objects, and want RABL to only render that object into JSON if a value is correct in a field.

Thanks SO!

Comment: I'm not sure the RABL template is the best place for that. Could you not scope the `@events` collection in the controller to only have the records you want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use conditionals in a RABL template.  That syntax looks right to me.  Is it giving you trouble of some sort?

Note that since you're comparing `event.charge` to `true`, you can leave out the comparison and just do this:

```
if (event.charge) {
  collection @events
  attributes :title, :date, :time, :venue, :description
}
```

**[UPDATE]** in response to comments with additional info.

OK, there are two issues at play here.

First, you probably do want to use a scope to narrow the collection of `@events` at the DB level.  Pulling rows from the DB and creating `ActiveRecord` objects from them is an expensive operation, so you don't want to do it for rows/objects that you aren't going to use.

The second issue has to do with how RABL templates are structured.  The template listed in your gist (https://gist.github.com/DevanB/6709271) should work great.

```
collection @events
attributes :title, :date, :time, :venue # ....
node(:imageUrl){|events| events.image.url(:main)}
node(:imageThumbUrl){|events| events.image.url(:thumb)}
```

This basically tells RABL to iterate over `@events` and for each one to build a JSON hash containing the listed attributes, and to build extra properties in the hash with the image URLs.  (I think you already know this, just want to be clear.)

You're running into trouble when you try to wrap the whole template with `if event.charge` because at that point there is no variable called `event`.  A reference to `event` works inside of the `node` blocks because as RABL loops through the `@events` collection it passes in the current event when it `yield`s to the supplied block, and the supplied block has named the variable that it receives `event`.  (I know that's a little circular.  I hope it makes sense.)

To illustrate conditionals, since I've already mentioned that filtering the collection is best done at the controller level, let's just say that you have an attribute that you want to populate based on the title of the event.  You could do something like this:

```
node(:is_special) do |event|
  if event.title == 'Some Special Event'
    'Aye, sir!'
  else
    'No way!'
  end
end
```

I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: the charge column is a boolean, defaults to 0. I wanted to render that event is the charge is 1. I tried your syntax, and I tried event.charge == 1, event.charge == "1", event.charge == "true" and event.charge == true

None of those worked unfortunately. It is still rendering every event.

Comment: Showing more of your RABL template might help.  It's very unclear what you're trying to do there.  The short answer to your question is that using an `if` in a RABL template is possible.  Outside of that it seems that maybe you're trying to do something a little non-standard.  Any chance you can post the controller action that sets up the template and the entire template that you're trying to use?

Comment: Maybe this will shed some light.
https://gist.github.com/DevanB/6709271

There is a charge field, and if a user pays for something, I change that boolean from 0 to 1. I could setup a scope. Would that only render the events that meet that scope?

Like if I did `@events = Event.upcoming.paid.all` in the index action.

Comment: OK, great, that gist helps a lot.  I just added an [UPDATE] to my original answer.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me! Thanks for the help Jeremy! :)

(I'm a bit new to Rails if you haven't figured that out one, so this helps a lot!)